# map integer values to chars in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mapping, chars

I've got a method that generates random strings:

```
def generate_letters(length)
    chars = 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    letters = ''
    length.times { |i| letters << chars[rand(chars.length)] }
    letters
  end
```

I want to map values to generated strings, e.g.(1):
A = 1, B = 2, C = 3 , e.g.(2):
if I generate ACB it equals to 132. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, how do you mean 'map'? Do you want to get number `132` base on generated string `'ACB'` or you need smth else?

Comment: yes - basing on that example, if my method generate `'BAC'` string I want to recognize it as `213`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that for concatenating these values:

```
s = 'ACB'
puts s.chars.map{ |c| c.ord - 'A'.ord + 10 }.join.to_i
# => 101211
```

and to sum them instead use [`Enumerable#inject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) method (see docs, there are some nice examples):

```
s.chars.inject(0) { |r, c| r + (c.ord - 'A'.ord + 10) } # => 33
```

or [`Enumerable#sum`](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/sum) if you're doing it inside Rails:

```
s.chars.sum { |c| c.ord - 'A'.ord + 10 } # => 33
```

Comment: it works! thanks, but could You describe, what each thing in Your code means? I want to understand it :)

Comment: ok, but wait! it doesn't work for all letters - e.g. K is 11th letter but it equals 1 :/ btw. if You can write that it will start counting from 10 (A = 10, B = 11, ... , Z = 35) it will be awesome!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. What should, for example, `KZ` be converted to? `2035`?

Comment: Updated the answer. Is that what you need now?

Comment: nothing - I've found description of methods which You've used, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How would you deal with the ambiguity for leters above 10 (J) ?
For example, how would you differentiate between `BKC=2113` and `BAAC=2113`?

Disregarding this problem you can do this:

```
def string_to_funny_number(str)
    number=''
    str.each_byte{|char_value| number << (1 + char_value - 'A'.ord).to_s}
    return number.to_i
end
```

This function will generate a correct int by concatenating each letter value (A=1,B=2,...)
Beware that this function doesn't sanitize input, as i am assuming you are using it with output from other function.

Comment: differentiate is not required in my case :) I want to add these numbers - e.g ABC = 1 + 2 + 3, AABA = 1 + 1 + 2 + 1 etc. during this transformation